# Create a cocoa touch framework can not use in main project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to learn cocoa touch framework, and I have code same as lots google result, but all not work.

I want to create a reuse code that can do write and read json file, and can called by main project app, so I create a simple cocoa touch framework just for test, I have drag the framework into main project, added it in embedded binaries, but when I build app, it always appears error message at `[let a = testClass]` this line in main project and below is error message:

> 'testClass' is unavailable: cannot find Swift declaration for this
>   class

is anywhere I make mistake?

---

**code of cocoa touch framework:**

```
import Foundation

public class testClass : NSObject {

    public static func tData() -> String {
        return "path"
    }
}
```

**code of app :**

```
import UIKit
import test

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let a = testClass
}
```

Comment: let a = testClass() or let a: testClass = whatever NSObject you have

Comment: since you have declared tData as static you can directly access by using class name like testClass. tData()

Comment: I change this line to : testClass.tData(), but shows error message : 'testClass' is unavailable: cannot find Swift declaration for this class.......But I have import test already......

Comment: Is your framework name `test`? because if not make sure you import the library correctly

Comment: Yes, the name is test. I know that is not good name this, I just want test cocoa framework so just use 'test'.

Comment: I copied your posted code into an Xcode Worse containing two iOS apps and a custom framework. `let a = testClass` has a build error saying you need some sort of constructor. So, as expected, `let a = testClass()` and let a = testClass.tData()` both build successfully. I'm surprised that your build recognizes `import test` but not `testClass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try adding the `init()` method to your `testClass`

```
public override init() {
    super.init()
}
```

Comment: Try removing the lib and adding it again after adding the init, and of course don’t forget the clean and build first the lib then the project

Comment: Did it. After 20 min try it again and again(delete cocoa touch project and create a new one), still the same error message...,

Comment: Ok, try this then, delete your library from the project, and instead of trying to add it from outside, create it directly inside your project by going `File->New->Target->Cocoa Touch Framework`, this should guarantee the link between the project and the lib, and then just add your code directly in the lib which is inside the project.

Comment: Sorry, still not work. Would you please send me some website for learn cocoa touch framework, I afraid waste your time.....ha ha :) .

Comment: Thank you very much, I am a beginner of swift, thanks for your help.

Comment: And do you know how to give a acceptance to a comment? I also a new in stackoverflow...,thank you ! I have another question need to make an acceptance.

Comment: Do you mean an answer? well technically my answer wasn't the right for you so you should not have accepted it, maybe just upvote, but i think you need at least 50 reputation for answers/comments upvote, anyway, don't worry about it im happy to help and i will take a look at your other question.